# Expected mean with two random variable

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose that a family has three children with equally likely outcomes. Let the random variable X denote the number of girls on the first birth, and Y denote the number of girl on the first two birth. Compute the following:
Write the probability for X and Y and use it to calculate E(X+Y) and Var(X+y)
i know E[x+Y]=E[X]+E[Y] can be done by individually calculating E[X] and E[Y] and summing it.

However, I am having trouble showing E[X+Y] in a probability distribution table and calculating it.

Comment: How is this off-topic? I asked the question from statistics book concerning probability.As I mentioned, I tried doing it individually and got the correct answer. However, I could not get the answer while I tried calculating it in the form E[X+Y] until I saw the answers.

Comment: For future improvement:
1. Try to include your working when you ask a question, rather than saying you tried or just show the final answer.
2. Use mathjax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X=0$, this implies that the child from the first birth was not a girl, and thus $Y$ can only be $0$ or $1$ for the second case. On the other hand, if $X=1$, implying a girl was born on the first birth, then $Y$ can only be $1$ (there was not another girl born) or $2$ (there was another girl born) for the second case. 
**Possible outcomes:**
$$X+Y=0$$
if a girl is not born on the first birth or the second birth ($X=0$ and $Y=0$).

$$X+Y=1$$
if a girl is not born on the first birth, but a girl is born on the second birth ($X=0$ and $Y=1$).
$$X+Y=2$$
if a girl is born on the first birth, and a girl is born on the second birth ($X=1$ and $Y=1$).
$$X+Y=3$$
if a girl is born on the first birth, and two girls are born on the second birth ($X=1$ and $Y=2$).

---

Because there are four possible scenarios, and $E[X+Y]$ must equal one, the probability for each $X+Y$ is $0.25$. Therefore:
$$E[X+Y]=0.25(0+1+2+3)=1.25.$$
We calculate the variance as :
$$Var(X+Y)=E[(X+Y)^2]-(E(X+Y))^2=3.25 -(1.25)^2=1.6875.$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

You just have to consider $4$ cases, each with equal probability. Fill in the blank

If first birth is a girl, second birth is a girl, then $X+Y=?$

If first birth is a girl, second birth is a boy, then $X+Y=?$

If first birth is a boy, second birth is a girl, then $X+Y=?$

If first birth is a boy, second birth is a boy, then $X+Y=?$

Computation of other parts should be direct now.